# Want to know whether mysql is installed and how to connect it using sqlyog?

Tags: mysql

First of all I am introduced to mysql today.

I have installed mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.3-win32.msi on my machine.

**Can you answer my following questions:**

```
1. Is MySql installed? how to know?
2. What is default database? 
3. What is default credentials? How to connect MySql using sqlyog?
```

Sorry I asked very basic questions.

Comment: What is the error when you to connect from SQLyog?

Comment: Connection related issues: http://faq.webyog.com/category/7/connection-issues.html

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is MySql installed? how to know?

Please go services.msc from run command and check the mysql service

> 1. What is default database?

i am not sure about this but there is no default database in mysql. u have to use command `use <database_name>` for ex. `use dummydb`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no service with name mysql. Does that mean it is not installed.